# Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's

Tags: errors, amsmath, overset

Sorry about the previous errors in the code.

Could any one help with the numbering in the \overset or \underset in equations?

I need to add number above/below certain variables in the equations because I have so many variables. And the equations are very long. I consider to use the counter to auto-number the variables in equations. I tried the following code, but it seems that the \overset and \underset conflicts with the label of equation.

I got the following errors:

```
Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'Eq1' will be lost. Y & = \overset{\dln{aaa}}{\boxed{a}}
```

Does anyone please help me with it. Thanks a lot. The code is here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\newcounter{rtaskno}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\dln}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{rtaskno}%
    \thertaskno\label{#1}}

\begin{document}

Here is the equation:\\

\begin{equation}\label{Eq1} % I need the Eq. number
\begin{aligned} % I need the aligned equation
Y & = \overset{\dln{aaa}}{\boxed{a}} x_1  \\ % I need the aaa to be auto numbered
& + \underset{2}{\boxed{b}} x_2  % I need the bbb to be auto numbered
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Here is how to refer \dln{aaa}. % I need to refer the number indexed by aaa

\end{document}
```

This is what I want:
[image]

Comment: Please consider cleaning up your previous question before asking a new one.

Comment: As I told you in your other question: You can't have more than one label in an `equation` environment -- the `\dln` macro is logically wrong

Comment: Thank you. I deleted the previous post. I have a large number of coefficients/variables such as "a", "b", in the equations which I need to label. I can directly number them in the \overset or \underset. But if I insert a new number at the beginning, I have to change all the numbers affected. So, I hope to label the coefficients/variables using refstepcounter and refer them in the text through \dln{aaa}.

Comment: Thank you Christian. Is there any other way to deal with it? Or, I have to use \underset{1}{\boxed{a}} directly?

Comment: How about `\begin{equation}\label{Eq1} 
\begin{aligned} 
Y & = \overset{\ref{Eq1}}{\boxed{a}} x_1  \\ 
& + \underset{\the\numexpr\theequation+1}{\boxed{b}} x_2  
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}` ?

Comment: Hi marmot, thank you for your reply. There is no error but I am afraid it is what I want. The numbering of the coefficients depends on the number of equation. Plus, I also need to refer the number lablled by "aaa".

Comment: I have a solution but it is just OK and not too much convenient. I used \newcounter{aaa} and \setcounter{aaa}{2} in a file named "input.tex" which I will include it. Then in the main tex file, I use the \overset{\arabic{aaa}}. Any time if I need to change the number of "aaa" or lots of other numbering, I go to "input.tex" to change the number one by one. It is still not convenient.

Comment: @Yuan: What about [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/iK2mKkEZ)?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer actually the equation enviornment doesn't have that restriction, it is the ams alignments (to avoid problems with the fact that they are evaluated twice, to measure things)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, I know -- I should have written `ams` style of equation

Comment: @Circumscribe I don't think the OP wants `\tag` here, wants `\label` to work with a second counter in addition to `equation`, see my answer.

Comment: @Circumscribe both `\tag` and the usual automatic numbering both require the `\label` redefinition.

Comment: @Circumscribe normally `\label` has to be in the same group as the `\refstepcounter` (and after it) hence the FAQ about caption and label, but in an alignment the counter is incremented in a hidden cell at the end, and because of measuring the `\label` would be written twice and generate duplicate label errors

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\zzlabel#1{\ifmeasuring@\else\ltx@label{#1}\fi}
\makeatletter


\newcounter{rtaskno}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\dln}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{rtaskno}%
    \thertaskno\zzlabel{#1}}

\begin{document}

Here is the equation:% never \\ at and of paragraph
\begin{equation}\label{Eq1} % I need the Eq. number
\begin{aligned} % I need the aligned equation
Y & = \overset{\dln{aaa}}{\boxed{a}} x_1  \\ % I need the aaa to be auto numbered
& + \underset{\dln{bbb}}{\boxed{b}} x_2  % I need the bbb to be auto numbered
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Here is how to refer aaa: \ref{aaa}. % I need to refer the number indexed by aaa

Here is how to refer bbb: \ref{bbb}. % I need to refer the number indexed by aaa

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much David for solving my problem. It works very well. Thank you marmot, Christian, Werner, and Circumscribe. I really appreciate your discussion and suggestions.

Comment: There's no explanation of what was changed here relative to the original code.